# ¿Es posible revertir el estado de "desuso" de una palabra?

Tags: rae, dle, diccionarios

Como bien está explicado en [esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23968/c%c3%b3mo-se-decide-si-una-palabra-se-tiene-que-marcar-como-en-desuso-o-eliminarla) y [esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17437/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-proceso-para-eliminar-una-palabra-del-drae/17642#17642) página, ciertas palabras que caen en desuso se mueven del diccionario principal de la lengua española al diccionario histórico de la lengua.

Por ejemplo, la palabra "aballenar" no está incluida en el DRAE (buscarla [acá](http://dle.rae.es/)), pero sí está disponible en el Nuevo diccionario histórico del español (NDHE) (ver [acá](http://web.frl.es/DH/org/login/Inicio.view;jsessionid=C3E612964727D70E78AB3535269B4B1F)).

¿Qué pasa si la palabra vuelve a usarse? Por ejemplo, puedo introducir "aballenar" en los libros que escribo. ¿Es ésto suficiente para traer válidamente una palabra del pasado al presente? ¿Cuál es el criterio para "des-desusar" una palabra? ¿Hay ejemplos históricos de esto?

Comment: Meramente emplear una palabra una persona en un libro no sería suficiente, tendría que llegar a disfrutar de uso general —que podría ser tanto en todo el mundo hispánico o dentro de ciertos sectores como es el caso de jerga especializada.  No puedo pensar en ejemplos.  Lo más probable, imagino, es que vuelva una palabra, pero con un significado nuevo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Claro que es posible! Como se comentó en [*¿Cómo elige la RAE las palabras que son “válidas”?*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17429/1674) y tantos otros lugares, la RAE hace de notario de la lengua:

> La tarea de la RAE es registrar el lenguaje tal y como es hablado por sus hablantes.
>
> Si una gran mayoría de sus hablantes usan una determinada palabra, la RAE la registra. Generalmente como un vulgarismo/coloquianismo, cuando la palabra se normaliza en la sociedad, pasa a ser una palabra más.

Esto está más detallado en una respuesta a [*¿Durante cuántos años debe aparecer una palabra en textos escritos para que la RAE la recoja en el diccionario?*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19900/1674):

> Juαn Vte. Sαntαcreu: hola, buenas noches @perezreverte por favor, ¿cuantos años hace falta que una palabra circule para que la RAE la admita?
>
> Arturo Pérez-Reverte: @JVSantacreu Cinco, si hay documentación escrita. Si es usada por los hispanoahablantes (50 millones aquí, 400 allí) de foma general.

Teniendo en cuenta lo dicho en [*¿Cuál es el proceso para eliminar una palabra del DRAE?*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17642/1674):

> Las palabras no se eliminan *nunca*. Solo por desuso las palabras que salen del diccionario se transfieren al "[Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico)", que es un diccionario de diccionarios, tal y como se describe en la propia página de la RAE.

Que más o menos coincide con lo que se comenta en [*¿Cómo se decide si una palabra se tiene que marcar como “en desuso” o eliminarla del diccionario?*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23968/1674).

Esto nos hace ver que una palabra que haya pertenecido alguna vez al diccionario, seguirá estando allí, aunque tal vez marcada como en desuso. Veo esto como una manera de evitar una proliferación innecesaria de términos ante la ausencia de una palabra para definirlos: *ey*, está diciendo la RAE, *antes de inventar algo nuevo fíjate en si ya existe*.

Por tanto, y resumiendo:

- una palabra marcada como en desuso siempre estará allí disponible para volver.
- su reincorporación al habla normal dependerá de su uso, que deberá ser prolongado e intenso para que los académicos la consideren una palabra más.

Como vimos en los comentarios, la [*arroba*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3ljwHF8) es un caso de palabra que ha recuperado su uso pero con una nueva acepción: de medida de peso durante muchos años pero no actualmente, ha pasado a referirse generalmente al símbolo `@`, cuya nueva acepción fue añadida hace pocos años.
Ahora mismo no caigo ni he podido encontrar palabra alguna cuyo significado cayera en desuso y posteriormente se recuperara con ese mismo sentido.

Nos queda la duda de si [la RAE tiene algún criterio a la hora de consultar textos en Internet para dar forma a su diccionario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21035/1674): es algo a lo que aún no hemos encontrado respuesta.

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta! ¡Gracias! Empero, el caso de arroba me parece distinto, puesto que se trata de una nueva acepción. De cierta manera, puede ser visto como una nueva palabra, que es homónima de la arroba en desuso. Mi pregunta concierne específicamente al retorno de acepciones en desuso.

Comment: @luchonacho llevas razón y ya me lo habías indicado en los comentarios. Edité para clarificar este caso. La cuestión es que el caso que planteas es plenamente posible, pero no pude encontrar ninguno

Comment: Por un mejor cras !!